# Are papers presented special sessions regarded inferior?

Tags: publications, phd

I am doing my PHD in computer-engineering (1st year), and am publishing at computer science and hardware conferences. 
My department receives requests all the time, on confernces with high probability of acceptance. (Usually there are too few submissions, so they request for more) These conferences are prestigious, however the sessions, I participate are very specific to a certain project or topic.

There is a lot of progress on my research, but since I am publishing a lot, it is dilluted into more publications. 
Can this later hurt my reputation, if I publish extensively on these sessions?

Comment: I think there is something missing here. You say that these conferences send out requests for additional papers with high chance of acceptance because they are lacking submissions. But you also say that these are prestigious conferences. These two things are pretty mutually exclusive.

Comment: Maybe prestigious is the wrong term. But they are good conferences. These special sessions are kind of decoupled from the main conference, and are usually seperately promoted.

Comment: @tonysdg Can you please turn your comment into an answer so that I can vote for it?

Comment: @jakebeal Done.

Answer (score 2):

Is this a co-located conference/workshop? Based on what I've been told by my adviser/post-docs (I'm also first-year CPE PhD), these types of places aren't where you want the bulk of your research going. You're better off aiming for a higher quality paper at the main conference - it looks better on a CV, and it's far more prestigious.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are the Ph.D. Candidate in Computer Science, so more than likely you will be able to answer your own question much better than we can for this specific topic.

Ask yourself: Is the subject of your talk at an appropriate Ph.D. level discourse, and will the audience be able to 'follow' and provide valuable feedback for your project? It is entirely understandable that there will be many small niches for any scientific discipline. As long as you are presenting adequate research for the Ph.D. level and the audience is able to follow along, these are very valuable presentation opportunities.